# JSON results showing first array ok, but the nested arrays are [Object, object]

Tags: html, json, ajax

I am pulling information from a wordnik api, for the word of the day, I'm trying to get the array information, but the first part of the array works but the parts that are nested arrays within are appearing as object, object

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $.getJSON( "http://api.wordnik.com/v4/words.json/wordOfTheDay?api_key=a2a73e7b926c924fad7001ca3111acd55af2ffabf50eb4ae5", function( data ) {
    var items = [];

    $.each(data, function( key, val) {
      items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'><b>"+ key+ ":</b> " + val +  "</li>" );
    });

    $( "<ul/>", {
      "class": "my-new-list",
      html: items.join( "" )
    }).appendTo( "#james2" );
  });
</script>
```

Comment: My Codepen link is http://codepen.io/jamesfarrington/pen/yOMdJV

Comment: you have only iterate through one loop you have to do logic for nested loop to display all value

Answer (score 1):

Try JSON.stringify() method on object.

```
$.each(data, function( key, val) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'><b>"+ key+ ":</b> " + JSON.stringify(val) +  "</li>" );
  });
```